# Splitting a large matrix

Tags: arrays, julia, timing

I'm using Julia to ingest a large two dimensional data array (`data`) of size 1000 x 32768; I need to break up the array into smaller square arrays along both dimensions. For instance, I would like to break `data` into a grid of smaller, square arrays similar to the following image:

[image]

Note that no pixels get left out -- when another square cannot be fit in along either axis, the last possible array of square pixels is returned as another array (hence the shifted pink squares on the right hand side).

Currently, I'm doing this through a function I built to decimate the raw dataset:

```
function decimate_square(data,fraction=4)

    # Read size of input data / calculate length of square side
    sy,sx = size(data)
    square_side = Int(round(sy/fraction))

    # Number of achievable full squares
    itersx,itersy = [Int(floor(s/square_side)) for s in [sx,sy]]

    # Find left/right X values
    for ix in 1:itersx
        if ix!=itersx
            # Full sliding square can be calculated
            left = square_side*(ix-1) + 1
            right = square_side*(ix)
        else
            # Capture last square of data
            left = sx-square_side + 1
            right = sx
        end

        # Find top/bottom Y values for each X
        for iy in 1:itersy
            if iy!=itersy
                # Full sliding square can be calculated
                top = square_side*(iy-1) + 1
                bottom = square_side*(iy)
            else
                # Capture last square of data
                top = sy-square_side + 1
                bottom = sy
            end

            # Record data in 3d stack
            cursquare = data[top:bottom,left:right]
            if (ix==1)&&(iy==1); global dstack=cursquare
            else; dstack=cat(dstack,cursquare,dims=3)
            end
        end
    end
    return dstack
end
```

Which currently takes ~20 seconds to run:

```
rand_arr = rand(1000,32768)
t1 = Dates.now()
dec_arr = decimate_square(rand_arr)
t2 = Dates.now()
@info(t2-t1)

[ Info: 19666 milliseconds
```

This is the biggest bottleneck of my analysis. Is there a pre-built function that I can use, or is there a more efficient way to decimate my array?

Comment: It's better to use proper integer division with `div` (and `cld`/`fld` etc.) than the `Int(floor(s/square_side))` business. `div(s, square_side)` is a single instruction instead of three, and much more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take `view`s as Przemyslaw Szufel suggests, and the `CartesianIndex` type comes in handy for selecting blocks of the matrix.

```
julia> function squareviews(data, fraction = 4)
          squareside = floor(Int, size(data, 1) / fraction)
          
          [@view(M[CartesianIndex(ix-squareside+1, iy-squareside+1):CartesianIndex(ix, iy)])
             for ix in squareside:squareside:size(data, 1),
                 iy in squareside:squareside:size(data, 2)]
       end
squareviews (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> result = squareviews(M)
4×40 Matrix{SubArray{Int64, 2, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}, UnitRange{Int64}}, false}}:
 [346 392 … 746 429; 380 193 … 476 757; … ; 424 329 … 285 427; 591 792 … 710 891]   …  [758 916 … 7 185; 26 846 … 631 808; … ; 945 713 … 875 137; 793 655 … 400 322]
 [55 919 … 402 728; 292 238 … 266 636; … ; 62 490 … 913 126; 293 475 … 492 20]         [53 8 … 146 365; 216 673 … 157 909; … ; 955 635 … 332 945; 354 913 … 922 272]
 [278 966 … 128 334; 700 560 … 226 701; … ; 529 398 … 17 674; 237 830 … 4 788]         [239 274 … 983 911; 591 669 … 762 675; … ; 213 949 … 917 903; 336 890 … 633 578]
 [723 483 … 135 283; 729 579 … 1000 942; … ; 987 383 … 764 544; 682 942 … 376 179]     [370 859 … 444 566; 34 106 … 320 161; … ; 310 41 … 868 349; 719 341 … 718 800]
```

This divides the data matrix into blocks such that `result[2, 3]` gives the square that is 2nd from the top and 3rd from the left. (My matrix `M` was 100x1000 in size, so there are 100/25 = 4 blocks vertically and 1000/25 = 40 blocks horizontally.)

If you want the results linearly like in your original function, you can instead have the second line of the function be:

```
julia> function squareviews(data, fraction = 4)
          squareside = floor(Int, size(data, 1) / fraction)
          
          [@view(M[CartesianIndex(ix-squareside+1, iy-squareside+1):CartesianIndex(ix, iy)])
             for iy in squareside:squareside:size(data, 2)
             for ix in squareside:squareside:size(data, 1)]
       end
squareviews (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> squareviews(M)
160-element Vector{SubArray{Int64, 2, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}, UnitRange{Int64}}, false}}:
```

(Note the subtle changes in the `for` syntax - the `iy` comes before `ix` here, there's no comma, and there's an extra `for`.)

This returns a vector of square matrices (views).

Your original function returned a three-dimensional matrix, in which you'd access values as `originalresult[i, j, k]`. Here, the equivalent would be `result[k][i, j]`.

Comment: Although it doesn't address the finer point of my issue (breaking up an array into squares, where the array itself does cannot be perfectly divided by squares of any size), this solves 95% of my problem. Accepting because of the implementation and explanation of the `result[i,j]` indices. Thank you!

Comment: "breaking up an array into squares, where the array itself does cannot be perfectly divided by squares of any size" I tried to accommodate for that, the `:` ranges should automaticaly take care of that. For eg. a 101x1000 matrix also gets divided 25x25 views with the last row discarded (as in the original code). Have you tried it out, and can you mention in which case it doesn't address that need? I only tested it with that one case of 101x1000, so may have missed other cases.

Comment: You're correct -- a 101x1000 matrix gets divided into 25x25 views, and the last row is discarded. In the (terribly inefficient) function I wrote, a fifth row is provided that includes rows 76:101 as a separate square. This way, you're not throwing away data, but the last square will admittedly contain a great deal of redundant data.

Comment: Ah. That may have been your intention, but if you try out your function with a `101 x 1000` matrix, or a `100 x 1010` matrix, its result is a `25 x 25 x 160` array i.e. it has only 100000 elements, not the original 101000. That's why I assumed you wanted to discard the extra elements. (Trying out `102 x 1000` matrix, only 77k elements are returned, so even more is discarded.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of stuff going on in your code with is not recommended and making things slow.  Here's a somewhat idiomatic solution, with the additional bonus of generalizing to arbitrary ranks:

```
julia> function square_indices(data; fraction=4)
           splits = cld.(size(data), fraction)
           return Iterators.map(CartesianIndices, Iterators.product(Iterators.partition.(axes(data), splits)...))
       end
square_indices (generic function with 1 method)
```

The result of this is an iterator over `CartesianIndices`, which are objects that you can use to index your squares.  Either the regular `data[ix]`, or `view(data, ix)`, which does not create a copy.  (Different fractions per dimension are possible, try `test_square_indices(println, 4, 4, 4; fraction=(2, 1, 1))`.)

And to see whether it works as expected:

```
julia> function test_square_indices(f, s...; fraction=4)
           arr = reshape(1:prod(s), s...)
           for ix in square_indices(arr; fraction)
               f(view(arr, ix))
           end
       end
test_square_indices (generic function with 1 method)

julia> # just try this on some moderatly costly function
       @btime test_square_indices(v -> inv.(v), 1000, 32768)
  81.980 ms (139 allocations: 250.01 MiB)

julia> test_square_indices(println, 9)
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]

julia> test_square_indices(println, 9, 5)
[1 10; 2 11; 3 12]
[4 13; 5 14; 6 15]
[7 16; 8 17; 9 18]
[19 28; 20 29; 21 30]
[22 31; 23 32; 24 33]
[25 34; 26 35; 27 36]
[37; 38; 39;;]
[40; 41; 42;;]
[43; 44; 45;;]

julia> reshape(1:9*5, 9, 5)
9×5 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 9, 5) with eltype Int64:
 1  10  19  28  37
 2  11  20  29  38
 3  12  21  30  39
 4  13  22  31  40
 5  14  23  32  41
 6  15  24  33  42
 7  16  25  34  43
 8  17  26  35  44
 9  18  27  36  45

julia> test_square_indices(println, 4, 4, 4; fraction=2)
[1 5; 2 6;;; 17 21; 18 22]
[3 7; 4 8;;; 19 23; 20 24]
[9 13; 10 14;;; 25 29; 26 30]
[11 15; 12 16;;; 27 31; 28 32]
[33 37; 34 38;;; 49 53; 50 54]
[35 39; 36 40;;; 51 55; 52 56]
[41 45; 42 46;;; 57 61; 58 62]
[43 47; 44 48;;; 59 63; 60 64]

julia> reshape(1:4*4*4, 4, 4, 4)
4×4×4 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 4, 4, 4) with eltype Int64:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  5   9  13
 2  6  10  14
 3  7  11  15
 4  8  12  16

[:, :, 2] =
 17  21  25  29
 18  22  26  30
 19  23  27  31
 20  24  28  32

[:, :, 3] =
 33  37  41  45
 34  38  42  46
 35  39  43  47
 36  40  44  48

[:, :, 4] =
 49  53  57  61
 50  54  58  62
 51  55  59  63
 52  56  60  64
```

---

Here's a bit of an illustration of how this works:

```
julia> data = reshape(1:9*5, 9, 5); fraction = 3;

julia> size(data)
(9, 5)

julia> # chunk sizes
       splits = cld.(size(data), fraction)
(3, 2)

julia> # every dimension chunked
       Iterators.partition.(axes(data), splits) .|> collect
(UnitRange{Int64}[1:3, 4:6, 7:9], UnitRange{Int64}[1:2, 3:4, 5:5])

julia> # cross product of all chunks
       Iterators.product(Iterators.partition.(axes(data), splits)...) .|> collect
3×3 Matrix{Vector{UnitRange{Int64}}}:
 [1:3, 1:2]  [1:3, 3:4]  [1:3, 5:5]
 [4:6, 1:2]  [4:6, 3:4]  [4:6, 5:5]
 [7:9, 1:2]  [7:9, 3:4]  [7:9, 5:5]
```

Comment: OK, I see now that this doesn't fulfull the requirement of left-shifting the rightmost box to make all sized equally. But nevertheless it's a general-purpose rectangle partition, so I'll leave it for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You could just go with views. Suppose you want to slice your data into 64 matrices, each having size 1000 x 512. In that case you could do:

```
dats = view.(Ref(rand_arr),Ref(1:1000), [range(1+(i-1)*512,i*512) for i in 1:64])
```

The time for this on my machine is 600 nanoseconds:

```
julia> @btime view.(Ref($rand_arr),Ref(1:1000), [range(1+(i-1)*512,i*512) for i in 1:64]);
  595.604 ns (3 allocations: 4.70 KiB)
```

Comment: In my example, I meant to illustrate that I want to divide the large array along both dimensions -- say 300 x 300 pixels -- so that I get 4 squares in the vertical dimension, and 110 divisions along the horizontal dimension. (I get 4 squares vertically, because I get three tiled 300x300 squares, and one that is offset such that it captures the last 300x300 array possible.)